# How treat `include-what-you-use` warnings as errors with `cmake`

Tags: cmake, static-analysis, iwyu

Is it possible to treat `include-what-you-use` warnings as errors using `cmake`?

I am playing around with `include-what-you-use` trying to integrate it into our `cmake` build process. The desired behaviour is to stop the build process when `include-what-you-use` generates a report, then print a warning. Currently, the build continues.

The tool is integrated to the `cmake` build process thanks to:

```
find_program(IWYU NAMES include-what-you-use)
if(IWYU)
  message(STATUS "Using include-what-you-use")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_INCLUDE_WHAT_YOU_USE ${IWYU})
endif()
```

I also add the `Werror` flag to my `cmake` target.

Comment: Yes it is, but I don't know how. I would search for how people have integrated more common static analysis tools, like `clang-tidy`, and just replace the other tool with `iwyu`.

Comment: Does the `include-what-you-use` program accept options to force an *error* for each report, instead of a warning?

Comment: @squareskittles `include-what-you-use` options isn't that clear hence my question. I think I set properly `cmake` side to treat warnings as errors (I use also `clang-tidy` and it works like a charm on that side).

Comment: `include-what-you-use` returns `2` on success so what I've done to integrate it with my (non-`cmake`) build is to wrap it in a little bash script that simply does `/usr/local/bin/include-what-you-use "$@" ; rv=$? ; if [ $rv -eq 2 ]; then rv=0; fi ; exit $rv`

Comment: You can list the command line options for `include-what-you-use` by providing a `-h` or `--help`, but I don't think there is an option to force an *error*. I think a solution would depend on the type of Makefile generator used.

Comment: @squareskittles No, there is no such option which is why I've wrapped it in a script to convert its exit code for success to the usual `0` for success as I described above.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Your solution doesn't work properly for build based on cmake

Comment: @AlexisLeProvost We have integrated `clang-tidy` in our `cmake` builds at work, making the builds fail if `clang-tidy` reports a failure. I don't see my `iwyu` should be any different when using a wrapper like the obove. Too bad I'm not good at `cmake` ...